# How to set default value for dynamic param?

Tags: powershell

I tried to add System.ComponentModel.DefaultValueAttribute to AttributeCollection of RuntimeDefinedParameter, but it does't work..

Answer (score 4):

Chrissy's example is probably the correct way to do it, but I was unable to retrieve the default value. The parameter does not exist in $PSBoundParameters when default value is specified.

The "workaround" we applied was to bind $PSBoundParameter["Background"] to the value we want as default. `$PSBoundParameters["Background"] = "Transparent"`

Extending Chrissy's example:

```
DynamicParam  {
    [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
    $colorlist = [System.Enum]::GetNames([System.Drawing.KnownColor])

    $attributes = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
    $attributes.ParameterSetName = "__AllParameterSets"
    $attributes.Mandatory = $false

    # Background color
    $validationset = New-Object -Type System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute -ArgumentList $colorlist
    $collection = New-Object -Type System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]
    $collection.Add($attributes)
    $collection.Add($validationset)
    $background = New-Object -Type System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter("Background", [String], $collection)
    $PSBoundParameters["Background"] = "Transparent"

    $newparams = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary
    $newparams.Add("Background", $background)

    return $newparams
}
```

Comment: This was the only way I was able to have a dynamic parameter with a default value myself. Thanks, Tomas!

Answer (score 3):

As Bartek suggested, the Value property can be used as seen in the code below

```
DynamicParam  {
    [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
    $colorlist = [System.Enum]::GetNames([System.Drawing.KnownColor])

    $attributes = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
    $attributes.ParameterSetName = "__AllParameterSets"
    $attributes.Mandatory = $false

    # Background color
    $validationset = New-Object -Type System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute -ArgumentList $colorlist
    $collection = New-Object -Type System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]
    $collection.Add($attributes)
    $collection.Add($validationset)
    $background = New-Object -Type System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter("Background", [String], $collection)
    $background.Value = "Transparent"

    $newparams = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary
    $newparams.Add("Background", $background)

return $newparams
}
```

The important line here is $background.Value = "Transparent" where $background is a RunTimeDefinedParameter.

For those that are curious. I initial tried to use it as an attribute, but there is no .Value available within ParameterAttributes.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:

I found an error in my PowerShell function, `Test-DynamicParameter`, which led to an erroneous conclusion. Below, in the PowerShell function, I will comment out the erroneous line. Also, the very last example output has changed. Again, I will annotate the changes.**

OK, so everyone who has answered is correct in how to set the "default" value of a dynamic parameter. (Spoiler alert / tl;dr: there's no such thing.) Now, let me preface my answer by saying that the function I'm about to demonstrate was executed via PowerShell 5.1. Below is what I found in my testing.

First, the function I'm using to test dynamic parameters and default values:

```bsh
function Test-DynamicParameter {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [switch]$UseDynamicParameterDefault2000
    )

    dynamicparam {
        # $RequestTimeout parameter
        $attributeCollection = New-Object Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[Attribute]
        $attributeCollection.Add((New-Object Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute -Property @{ ParameterSetName = "__AllParameterSets" }))
        $attributeCollection.Add((New-Object Management.Automation.ValidateScriptAttribute { $_ -ge 0 }))

        $RequestTimeoutParameter = New-Object Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter RequestTimeout, int, $attributeCollection
        # This line uses an incorrect name for the dynamic parameter, which caused
        # incorrect results in my original post. The corrected line
        # appears below this commented out, incorrect line.
        #$RequestTimeoutParameter.Value = $(if ($PSBoundParameters.UseDynamicParameterDefault1) { 2000 } else { 120000 })
        $RequestTimeoutParameter.Value = $(if ($PSBoundParameters.UseDynamicParameterDefault2000) { 2000 } else { 120000 })

        $dynamicParams = New-Object Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary
        $dynamicParams.Add('RequestTimeout', $RequestTimeOutParameter)

        $dynamicParams
    }

    process {
        $RequestTimeoutParameter | Format-List

        if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('UseDynamicParameterDefault2000')) {
            Write-Host "`$PSBoundParameters contains 'RequestTimeout'? $($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('RequestTimeout'))"
            Write-Host "`$RequestTimeout default: 2000"
            if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('RequestTimeout')) {
                # UPDATE: The following line should have used $PSBoundParameters to access the RequestTimeout parameter and has been corrected below
                #Write-Host "`$RequestTimeout = $RequestTimeout (Bound)"
                Write-Host "`$RequestTimeout = $($PSBoundParameters['RequestTimeout']) (Bound)"
            } else {
                # UPDATE: To be safe, also access $RequestTimeout here via $PSBoundParameters
                #Write-Host "`$RequestTimeout = $RequestTimeout (Default Value)"
                Write-Host "`$RequestTimeout = $($PSBoundParameters['RequestTimeout']) (Default Value)"
            }
        } else {
            Write-Host "`$PSBoundParameters contains 'RequestTimeout'? $($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('RequestTimeout'))"
            Write-Host "`$RequestTimeout default: 120000"
            if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('RequestTimeout')) {
                Write-Host "`$RequestTimeout = $($PSBoundParameters['RequestTimeout']) (Bound)"
            } else {
                # UPDATE: Again, use $PSBoundParameters
                #Write-Host "`$RequestTimeout = $RequestTimeout (UnBound, Default Value)"
                Write-Host "`$RequestTimeout = $($PSBoundParameters['RequestTimeout']) (UnBound, Default Value)"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And now some tests executing the function (again, using PowerShell 5.1):

```
PS C:\> Test-DynamicParameter


Name          : RequestTimeout
ParameterType : System.Int32
Value         : 120000
IsSet         : True
Attributes    : {__AllParameterSets, System.Management.Automation.ValidateScriptAttribute}



$PSBoundParameters contains 'RequestTimeout'? False
$RequestTimeout default: 120000
$RequestTimeout =  (Unbound, Default Value)

PS C:\> Test-DynamicParameter -RequestTimeout 3000


Name          : RequestTimeout
ParameterType : System.Int32
Value         : 3000
IsSet         : True
Attributes    : {__AllParameterSets, System.Management.Automation.ValidateScriptAttribute}



$PSBoundParameters contains 'RequestTimeout'? True
$RequestTimeout default: 120000
$RequestTimeout = 3000 (Bound)

PS C:\> Test-DynamicParameter -UseDynamicParameterDefault2000

Name          : RequestTimeout
ParameterType : System.Int32
### UPDATE: Due to incorrect code, this line was wrong...
### Value         : 120000
Value         : 2000
IsSet         : True
Attributes    : {__AllParameterSets, System.Management.Automation.ValidateScriptAttribute}



$PSBoundParameters contains 'RequestTimeout'? False
$RequestTimeout default: 2000
$RequestTimeout =  (Default Value)

PS C:\> Test-DynamicParameter -UseDynamicParameterDefault2000 -RequestTimeout 3000


Name          : RequestTimeout
ParameterType : System.Int32
Value         : 3000
IsSet         : True
Attributes    : {__AllParameterSets, System.Management.Automation.ValidateScriptAttribute}



$PSBoundParameters contains 'RequestTimeout'? True
$RequestTimeout default: 2000
### UPDATE: This line is incorrect when the PowerShell function is corrected.
### $RequestTimeout = 3000 (Bound)
###
$RequestTimeout = 3000 (Bound)

PS C:\>
```

<del>OK, so I learned a few things from this output. One is that I was trying to use `$PSBoundParameters` while constructing the dynamic parameter in order to set its default value (to either 2000, or 120000). However, this doesn't work, as the parameters have not yet been processed.</del> *(I was wrong, you can use `$PSBoundParameters` while constructing dynamic parameters.)* What happens is the parameter is created, then the values sent into the cmdlet for the various parameters are bound. In the case where a value for the dynamic parameter is specified, the dynamic parameter's `Value` property is updated. In this sense, then, the `Value` property is **not** a default value for the dynamic parameter; it's ***the*** value for the parameter.

<del>So, in my function where I try to set the "default" value of the dynamic parameter contingent upon the value of other (bound) parameters, this doesn't work and the value `120000` is always set as the initial value for the dynamic parameter.</del> *(Due to my coding error, this was true. But once the code is corrected, this statement is false.)*

OK, but when I don't specify `-RequestTimeout <n>` to an invocation of the cmdlet, referring to `$RequestTimeout` in the cmdlet results in a null value. What gives? How do I get the default value I set on the parameter? That's easy. I still have access to the `$RequestTimeoutParameter` variable I used to build up the parameter definition. And as you can see in the output, I wrote that out and you can see the `Value` property is set. Furthermore, when `-RequestTimeout <n>` is specified, the `$RequestTimeoutParameter.Value` property is updated with the value passed in from the command invocation.

I hope this helps someone else out there.

Answer (score 2):

This might be obvious, but I didn't see anyone mention this specifically yet, but if you combine fourpastmidnights excellent explanation, chrissy's initial answer, and Tomas's clever suggestion.

You *can* assign the value of the Dynamic Param, which changes based on user provided input, to the $PSBoundParameter Dictionary dynamically, achieving the desired effect of providing an accesible default value when nothing is specified, but also updating it in the event user input is provided.

```
    dynamicParam {
    if ($Param1 -eq $True) {
        #Create Abstract Object
        $paramDictionary = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary
        $attributeCollection = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]

        #Define Param attributes
        $attribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
        $attribute.Mandatory = $false
        $attributeCollection.Add($attribute)

        #Create Param
        $Name = 'DynamicParam1'
        $dynParam = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter($Name, [bool], $attributeCollection)
        $dynParam.value = $true
        $paramDictionary.Add($Name, $dynParam)
        $PSBoundParameters["$name"] = $dynParam.Value
    }
    $paramDictionary
}
```

Thus this example will then let you access the value of `$PSBoundParameters.DynamicParam1` for either the default value `$true`, or the user provided value if one was supplied.

From what I can tell the line `$PSBoundParameters["$name"] = $dynParam.Value` must be after the "default" value assignment statement `$dynParam.value = $true`.

This was tested on PS 7.1

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work. Can you provide a full function that showcases this, and the command you use on it?

Comment: @Vopel Briefly looking at this based on what I see I believe it's not working for you because of the condition check. DynamicParam1 only becomes available if $Param1 exist. So depending on your use case add or remove that check. That check exist because of a related issue I ran across described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62799432/powershell-dynamic-param-that-references-a-static-param-errors-when-using-get-h

Mind you this was 2 years ago and I have not thoroughly reviewed this so I could be missing something. I'll check if I have time.

Comment: It doesn't work even with the condition check removed.

Answer (score 1):

System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter has 'Value' property, so I guess I would use it to set default value. It sort of works (when I debug script I can see this 'default' value using $PSCmdlet.GetDynamicParameters() ) but I had no luck accessing it in actual function (it's execution 'died' on $pscmdlet.GetDynamicParameters() call).

Anyway: when I specified value my function was showing bound value rather than default one.

Not sure if it helps, and TBH I hardly see any use case for default value when parameter is dynamic. Would love to see why you need it. :)

Comment: I need default value to make parameter is required. Like `function f($p = @(throw "p is required")) {}`

Comment: Wouldn't 'Mandatory' be a better choice than...?

Comment: No. Mandatory show dialog(or command line prompt), but my script have to work without human acts

Comment: A good use case for me is that, depending on the configuration of some other parameter value, the default value changes. (I'm writing a Cmdlet to modify an XML configuration file.) Granted, having a default value is not _strictly_ required, but it does serve as documentation for those using the Cmdlet. It's too bad dynamic parameters are inproperly affecting the `$PSBoundParameters` dictionary (at least, from a Cmdlet author perspective).

Comment: Looking at the documentation for `RuntimeDefinedParameter`, I wonder if setting the `Value` property results in the `IsSet` property becoming `true`, thereby populating `$PSBoundParameters`? So, if you first set `Value`, then (re-)set `IsSet` to `false`, maybe this will work? I'll try this and report back.

Comment: 2 updates: as of PSv5.1, dynamic parameters when not given a value during cmdlet invocation no longer show up in the `$PSBoundParameters` dictionary. Also, setting a value on the dynamic parameter during parameter creation does nothing in PSv5.1. There's no way (that I can tell) to gain access to the parameter value via `$PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.MyCommand.Parameters` since it doesn't expose the `Value` property of a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

It is not exactly what you need, but at least a good workaround (requires PowerShell 3.0):

You can set the default values for all parameters of all functions using `$PSDefaultParameterValues`. See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847819.aspx or use PowerShell help on `about_Parameters_Default_Values`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not check if the parameter was specified by the user and if not, provide a value for the parameter in the begin-block for instance;

```
function Get-Something {
    param()
    dynamicparam{
        <Definition of dynamic parameter "ThisIsADynamicParam">
    }
    begin {
        if (-not $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('ThisIsADynamicParam') {
            $PSBoundParameters.Add('ThisIsADynamicParam','DefaultValue')
        }

    }
}
```