# Powershell: Dynamic Param that references a Static Param Errors when using Get-Help. How to Suppress error?

Tags: powershell

A Module Variable

```
$ModVar = @{Value = Key}
```

Errors when using static Param `-Name`, as a key reference.

```
PS> help Test-Function

InvalidOperation: 
Line |
 214 |              $ModItem = $ModVar[$Name]
     |              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Index operation failed; the array index evaluated to null.
```

I believe this is because the Param `-Name` does not exist until execution time. The function otherwise works correctly when used, this error only happens when using `Get-Help`.

Is there a methodology for getting around the error?

I have tried:

```
If (!$Name) {$Name = "A_Key_in_ModVar"}
```

In an attempt to supply a dummy value when it doesn't detect a value in `-Name`, but this causes the function to always overwrite the value of `-Name`, even if the parameter `-Name` is provided with an explicit value from the terminal.

Gist Example: [GitHub to Get-KeyAndPeeleSchoolName](https://gist.github.com/phatmandrake/6a8ddc98843c66a83772f810d366dd24)

Code Snippet (full example above):

```
DynamicParam {

        $ParameterName = 'School'

        $RuntimeParameterDictionary = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary
        $AttributeCollection = New-Object System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]
        Write-Error $Name
        $attSet = $Table[$Name]
        Write-Error $attSet
        $ValidateSetAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute($attSet)
        $ValidateSetAttribute.ErrorMessage = "Value must be $attSet"
        $AttributeCollection.Add($ValidateSetAttribute)

    $ParameterAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
    $ParameterAttribute.ParameterSetName = "ParamSet1"
    $AttributeCollection.Add($ParameterAttribute)

        $RuntimeParameter = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter($ParameterName, [string], $AttributeCollection)
        $RuntimeParameterDictionary.Add($ParameterName, $RuntimeParameter)

        $RuntimeParameterDictionary
    }
```

Edit 1: Other issues I noticed.

Values for -Name that contains spaces prevent the Dynamic Param block containing `-School` from working.

Also when using ArgumentCompleter on `-Names`, the possible values with complex punction fail to completely autocomplete. This is probably because of the matching behavior, but any suggestions for how to make this behave would be great.

Also using " " quotes around a parameter value also prevent the argument completer from working, any suggestions for this would also be great.

Comment: This question is unclear to me. !re you using an actual dynamic parameter block ? If so, ArgumentCompleter is generally better at everything. If you meant "dynamic" by "I use a module variable in my function", then it is not a problem. I find it weird that there's an error on the call to help though. Can you post the function altogether (maybe reduce it to the smallest reproducible sample)

Comment: See Gist. See Edit 1 for other issues.

Comment: Why not drop the dynamic parameter and use a second argument completer ? The only difference, other than working better on all level, is that your result set won't be a validateset. Therefore you'll have to add an extra line to throw an error if the value is invalid.

Comment: I'll leave someone more knowledgeable answer on how to solve the problem specifically with dynamic parameter.

Comment: Well remember this is an example I whipped up, not the actual code I'm working with, but the error is the exact same, and the implementation of a Dynamic Param using a Argument Completer is also identical. I want to make it so that they can only select from a Valid Set of values for the Dynamic Param. I could handles this logic in the Begin Block, but it makes sense for it to be done during parameter validation so I want to understand how.

Comment: You could still do that through the addition of ValidateScript parameter attribute so if the value is outside of the argument completion values, therefore doing it at the parameter validation level.

Comment: Oooh Good point, as long as it can access the value of other parameters. That's a decent workaround. But I do lose the ability to hide the parameter. The dynamic part is a bit of a cherry on top.

Comment: I swear I tried this, but evidently wrapping insides of the RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary objects in an IF statement is sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping the `[RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary]` object and accompanying constructs in an IF statement resolved the issue. `-Name` does not exist pre-binding when `-Name` is not passed a value explicitly. It is also not available when `Get-Help` runs to analyze the makeup of the Function.

To resolve this, check for the existence of the parameter being referenced within the `DynamicParam` block to control its execution.

```
DynamicParam {

if ($Name) { #If $Name exist create Dynamic Param.

        $ParameterName = 'School'

        $RuntimeParameterDictionary = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary
        $AttributeCollection = New-Object System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]
        
        $attSet = $Table[$Name]
        $ValidateSetAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute($attSet)
        $ValidateSetAttribute.ErrorMessage = "Value must be $attSet"
        $AttributeCollection.Add($ValidateSetAttribute)

        $ParameterAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
        $ParameterAttribute.ParameterSetName = "ParamSet1"
        $AttributeCollection.Add($ParameterAttribute)

        $RuntimeParameter = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter($ParameterName, [string], $AttributeCollection)
        $RuntimeParameterDictionary.Add($ParameterName, $RuntimeParameter)

        $RuntimeParameterDictionary
    }
```

}