# How to set PowerShell PSDefaultParameterValues conditionally based on other parameters

Tags: powershell

Without going much into details on why am I even trying this out, is it possible to set `PSDefaultParameterValues` conditionally based on other parameter values?

Let's say I would like to set `-Force` if `ItemType` is `Directory` in `New-Item` call.

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues = @{ "New-Item:Force" = {
        # TODO: if Itemtype is Directory, return $true
        # else return default: false
        return $false
    }
}
New-Item -ItemType Directory
```

Problem is, that I can get the parameters used in `$args` but I do not have access to their values.

[image: debugger screenshot]

Comment: I believe you would need to use dynamic parameters for this. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11012514/584676) has several answers which should be of use to you.

Answer (score 1):

As you've observed, **the argument passed to your script block via the [automatic `$args` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#args) contains the *names* of the bound parameters in the `New-Item` call at hand, but lacks their *values***.

- This looks like an oversight, which [GitHub proposal #16011](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/16011) aims to correct.

The following **workaround** isn't foolproof, but may suffice  in practice:

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues = @{
  'New-Item:Force' = { 
    ($false, $true)[
      $args.BoundParameters.Contains('ItemType') -and 
      (Get-PSCallStack)[1].Position.Text -match '\bDirectory\b'
    ]
  }
}
```

You could tweak the regex to be stricter, but note that PowerShell's elastic syntax and parameter aliases make it hard to match a parameter name reliably; e.g., `-Type Directory`, `-it Directory` and `-ty Directory` are all acceptable variations of `-ItemType Directory`.

A **caveat** is that this **won't work if you pass the `Directory` argument to `-ItemType` in `New-Item` calls *via a variable***; e.g., `$type='Directory'; New-Item -ItemType $type ...` would *not* be recognized by the script block. Handling that case would require substantially more work.

---

Note:

- The parent call-stack entry, which you can obtain as the 2nd element of the call-stack array returned by [`Get-PSCallStack`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-pscallstack), contains the raw command text of the `New-Item` call at hand (in property `.Position.Text`), which the solution above examines.

  - However, since it is the *raw* command text, it doesn't include the *expanded* argument values that are ultimately seen by the command; that is, what variable references and expression *evaluate to* isn't directly available.
  - You could perform your own expansion, assuming you've reliably identified the variable reference / subexpression of interest, but note that, at least in principle, evaluating a subexpression can have *side effects* (and possibly also take a long time to execute), so effectively executing it *twice* may be undesirable.