# Why this $args[0] has BoundDefaultParameters, BoundParameters, and BoundPositionalParameters properties？

Tags: powershell

I am a beginner in PowerShell and am currently studying ***PowerShell Cookbook, 4th Edition***.

Chapter 1.5 of the Book says: **When PowerShell invokes your script block, $args[0] contains information about any parameters bound so far: BoundDefaultParameters, BoundParameters, and BoundPositionalParameters.**

Example code:

```
function RemoteConnector
{
    param(
        [Parameter()]
        $ComputerName,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        $Credential)

    "Connecting as " + $Credential.UserName
}

$credmap = @{}
$credmap["RemoteComputer1"] = Get-Credential
$credmap["RemoteComputer2"] = Get-Credential

$PSDefaultParameterValues["*:Credential"] = {
    if($args[0].BoundParameters -contains "ComputerName")
    {
        $cred = $credmap[$PSBoundParameters["ComputerName"]]
        if($cred) { $cred }
    }
}
```

Example of this in use:

```
PS > RemoteConnector -ComputerName RemoteComputer1
Connecting as UserForRemoteComputer1
PS > RemoteConnector -ComputerName RemoteComputer2
Connecting as UserForRemoteComputer2
PS > RemoteConnector -ComputerName RemoteComputer3

cmdlet RemoteConnector at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Credential: (...)
```

However, PowerShell Document states that **$args Contains an array of values for undeclared parameters that are passed to a function, script, or script block.** Because the `-ComputerName` parameter passed to the RemoteConnector function has been declared, So I think $args should be $null.

But the code works well. Why is this $args not $null, and $args[0] has BoundDefaultParameters, BoundParameters, and BoundPositionalParameters properties?

I can't understand this $args, I tried modifying the code to remove $args.

```
function RemoteConnector {
    param(
        [parameter()]
        $ComputerName,
        [parameter(Mandatory)]
        [pscredential]$Credential
    )
    "Connecting as " + $Credential.UserName
    "Password is " + $Credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password
}

$CredMap = @{}
$CredMap["RemoteComputer1"] = [pscredential]::new('User1', (ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'Password1' -AsPlainText))
$CredMap["RemoteComputer2"] = [pscredential]::new('User2', (ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'Password2' -AsPlainText))
$CredMap["default"] = [pscredential]::new('User3', (ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'Password3' -AsPlainText))

$PSDefaultParameterValues["*:Credential"] = {
    if ($PSBoundParameters["ComputerName"]) {
        switch ($PSBoundParameters["ComputerName"]) {
            'RemoteComputer1' { $CredMap["RemoteComputer1"] }
            'RemoteComputer2' { $CredMap["RemoteComputer2"] }
            default { $CredMap["default"] }
        }
    }
}
```

It also works well. But When I used it with Cmdlets(e.g. Invoke-Command), It not works. I think it's probably because $PSBoundParameters can only be used with scripts or functions. Is there anything similar to the $psboundparameters feature available for Cmdlets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me offer a what I hope is a comprehensive summary:

As noted in your question, **by design a *script block* that is specified as [`$PSDefaultParameterValues` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#psdefaultparametervalues)-entry value receives a single `[pscustomobject]` instance *as a positional argument*** with contextual information about the parameters that have been bound so far to the command being invoked.

- This is ***unrelated* to whether the target command is a binary or cmdlet or not, or whether a PowerShell-implemented command happens to be an [*advanced*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced) one or not**.
- Since *your script block* is *not* an advanced one, the simplest way to access this positional argument is via the [automatic `$args` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#args), i.e. as `$args[0]`, but you're free to formally declare a parameter for it and use that instead (e.g., `param([pscustomobject] $boundParamInfo)`; you can even make your script block an advanced one, though there's no advantage to doing so, and could even break, if and when the future enhancement discussed below is implemented).
- To recap the **properties of this `[pscustomobject]` instance**:

  - `.BoundParameters` ... the names (only!) of all parameters bound *so far*, irrespective of binding method.
  - `.BoundPositionalParameters` ... the *subset* of `.BoundParameters` that were bound *positionally*, if any.
  - `.BoundDefaultParameters` ... the *subset* of `.BoundParameters` that were bound via a *different* `$PSDefaultParameterValues` entry; note, however, that this information is virtually useless, because there is *no guaranteed order* in which `$PSDefaultParameterValues`-based defaults are assigned.
  - All three properties contain - case-*insensitive* -[`[HashSet[string]]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.HashSet-1) instances, which means:

    - You can *enumerate* them, e.g. with `foreach`
    - You can test for the presence of a specific name with `.Contains()` (e.g. `$args[0].BoundParameters.Contains('computername')`)
- It follows that all **these properties have a *major design limitation* as of PowerShell 7.4.0**:

  - They **only contain the bound parameters' *names*, not also their *values***.

    - [GitHub issue #16011](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/16011) aims to fix this problem.
  - **Workarounds for access to parameter *values* too**:

    - ***If* the target command happens to be a *script* or *function***, you can use the [automatic **`$PSBoundParameters`** variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#psboundparameters), as you've discovered, which **only works due to a *lucky accident***:

      - A `$PSDefaultParameterValues` script block-entry runs in a *child scope* of the target script or function, and therefore *happens to see* the latter's `$PSBoundParameters` instance. This should be considered an *implementation detail*, however; the proposal in the linked GitHub issue would be a proper solution.
    - For ***binary* cmdlets**, this does *not* work, as you've also discovered:

      - A ***limited* workaround** is available via **examining the raw invocation command line via `Get-PSCallStack`**, as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68956082/45375).

Answer (score 1):

> PowerShell Document states that **$args Contains an array of values for undeclared parameters that are passed to a function, script, or script block**.

That is accurate, and that is also what happens here.

The script block [assigned to `$PSDefaultParameterValues`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parameters_default_values) is processed at runtime by something called a **cmdlet parameter binder controller** - a component responsible for binding parameter argument values correctly against cmdlets, including advanced script functions.

The binder controller passes a custom object with those three properties [as a single positional argument when invoking the block](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/71ae6070c2ecfa27e4103894331ea94c616e6921/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/CmdletParameterBinderController.cs#L408-L409) - which is why you find it assigned to `$args[0]` inside the block.

The `BoundParameters` property contains an exact copy of the named values assigned to `$PSBoundParameters`, which is why it works the same regardless of which way you access the existing argument.